# Insert Select with Multiplication from other table

Tags: mysql

I want insert data to table1 from table2 where data in table2 multiplicated with value at table3.

table1 and table2 has same column (id,rangking,status,access,facility,popularity) (id is auto increment)
table2 has data :

id | rangking | status | access | facility | popularity

1 | 9 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 6

2 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 7

3 | 5 | 8 | 5 | 3 | 4

table3 has data :

id | value
c2 | 0.2
c3 | 0.5
c4 | 0.1
c5 | 0.3

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($koneksi, "SELECT value 
           FROM table3 WHERE id ='c2'") or die(mysqli_error($koneksi));
$c2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

$sql = mysqli_query ($koneksi, "SELECT value 
               FROM table3 WHERE id ='c3'") or die(mysqli_error($koneksi));
    $c3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

insert into table1 (rangking,status,access,facility,popularity) 
SELECT (rangking*$c2['value'] as Rank,status *$c3['value'] as Stat,access,facility,popularity) FROM table2
```

from that query I found error, any help?

Answer (score 1):

You select a column named `value` then you should accessing value in $c2   (and don't need  alias in select (for insert/select the values are assigned by position)

```
insert into table1 (a2,a3,a4,a5) 
SELECT (a2*$c2['value'] as A2,a3,a4,a5) FROM table2
```

..

```
$sqlTest = mysqli_query ($koneksi, "insert into table1 (a2,a3,a4,a5) 
    SELECT (a2*$c2['value'] as A2,a3,a4,a5) FROM table2") or die(mysqli_error($koneksi));
```

Comment: still has comment = mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: this error is not related  to my answer ... i have only post the query sql code  and  not  the mysqli_query ..code  .. at which query are you referring??

Comment: the SELECT command without ().. I mess myself. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself the multiple queries by using a join:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a2, a3, a4, a5)
SELECT table1.a2 * table3.value AS a2, table1.a3, table1.a4, table1.a5
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table3
  ON table3.id = :id
```

`:id` being a named parameter, which you can bind to the value of `'c2'` (or insert manually, depending on whether or not it's user input).

I used the `table3.id = :id` in the `ON` because that will for sure bind the result to the row selected, but if you have a proper association/foreign key you would want to use that instead.

In the future, it helps to name your columns something meaningful, not just `a1`, `a2`, etc.

Comment: actually it more complicated than just a1, a2. I just make it simple to make easy understanding other people see as other case.
I will multiplicate all its like (a2 * c2, a3 * c3, a4 * c4, a5 * c5) but nothing same id to join it.

Comment: Honestly, `a1...a5` is more confusing than actual names. Even when posting a question.

Comment: already edited it. I cant use JOIN because nothing same at table3.id with table2.id

Comment: You can use join here, it just will be a little different than most joins (in that you'll basically just be joining a singular row to your table).